# Can $xy=0$ be considered as a rectangular hyperbola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

This is just a simple yes or no question whether $xy=0$ can be considered as a rectangular hyperbola or not.

I was doing a sum where it said the following :

> If the straight line $3x + 4y = 24$ meets the axes at $A$ and $B$ and the line $4x + 3y = 24$ meets the axes at $C$ and $D$, then show that the points lie on a conic section which has to be an ellipse.

Well, I then thought that it lies on $xy=0.$
So is $xy=0$ a conic ?

Comment: Include your steps done to arrive at your claim that "it lies on $xy=0.$

Comment: A conic section is anything of the form $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ What is your conclusion?

Comment: Yes, $xy=0$ is a (degenerate) rectangular hyperbola; when you study conics, you learn to embrace degeneracies. (See, for instance, Wikipedia's ["Degenerate conic" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic).) ... That aside ... What a curious textbook question. Five points determine a conic, and the problem gives you four. By moving an arbitrary fifth point around, you can get whatever type of conic (ellipse, parabola, hyperbola) you like. Maybe the question is asking for a guarantee that an ellipse appears; but it's dead-simple to guarantee a *circle*, so where's the challenge?

Comment: yep my bad. got it. tnx. there can be any type of conic through those 4 points. so the question has to be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...  A pair of straight lines obtained by cutting a right circular cone through its apex. It is a degenerate conic with a sharp slope change at the origin. The combination curve of the x-y- axes.

Special case when in hyperbola set $ x\cdot y=c^2, c=0.$